# How Git Merge Work? Offline Or Online?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm Using Tortoise GIT to controll my Repos.

I have 2 branch A, B:

I switch A to B > merge A into B without pull, the result show an Error that I do not pull before.

I switch A to B > merge A into B with pull before, Everything work fine.

So, without pull request, I cannot merge with another branch because source code was not up to date.

And I think merge action requried a pull request before (code must up to date). But code up to date at git, so it may cause of Merge by Tortoise must happen at local (offline)?

So, How Git Merge Work? Offline Or Online?

[Sorry I'm not good at English, please help me to improve this post. Thanks!]

Comment: Can you put down your screenshot which you got?

Comment: @Nha Hoang Sorry, I'm a newbie, I cannot put any screenshot cause of policy.

Comment: How did you merge?  You *can* merge a remote branch locally which would require that your local branch be up to date...

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, My local branch was not up to date. So, right answer is **local branch must to be up to date** to merge, thank you!

Comment: Merges work offline. Git works offline.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thank you, Where can I read it?

Comment: What would you like to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid any issue you will want to be online, as you are not able to push your edits to a remote branch while offline.

Starting in branch A(local):

Pull branch A(remote).
Make your edits to branch A(local).
Push your edits to branch A(remote).
Checkout branch B(local).
Pull branch B(remote).
Merge branch A(local) into branch B(local).
Push your edits to branch B(remote).

I have left out the commit message portion of it as it seems unnecessary to point out.